# Check if a word in a string is contained in a set

Tags: java, nlp

I have a set called namePrefixSuffixSet which has possible prefix and suffix information. E.g Jr, Mr., Mrs., Attorney General etc.

I am extracting proper nouns from a sentence and checking them against this set to see if the proper noun contains a prefix or a suffix. If it does then I classify this proper noun as a person. e.g John Briggs Jr

I'm providing a snippet of code on how I am doing this. I am unable to get a match.

```
if (namePrefixSuffixList.contains(entry.getKey().toLowerCase())){
                    Set<String> roleStrings = roleStringsMap.containsKey("PERSON") 
                        ? roleStringsMap.get("PERSON") : new HashSet<String>();
                        roleStrings.add(entry.getKey());
                        roleStringsMap.put(SemanticRole.PERSON, roleStrings);
                        continue;
          }
```

In the code above `entry.getKey() = John Briggs Jr`

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: does namePrefixSuffixList contain "john briggs jr" ?

Comment: No it only contains the suffix 'Jr', not the entire name.

Comment: How do you expect a match then?

Comment: But you are checking if it `contains("John Briggs Jr")`. You have to split entry.getKey() into its parts and do a contains check with those.

Comment: Right, so that's what I was confused about. I thought this will match the Jr in John Briggs Jr to the Jr in the set.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS But would that work for a multi word prefix like attorney general? Coz then i'd be matching 'attorney' against' attorney general' in the set right?

Comment: You're right that this wouldn't work if some of your titles contain spaces themself. In that case you could loop through your namePrefixSuffixList set and do a contains check on the String itself (and not the set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are calling the contains method of your list which will only return true if one of the entries is an exact match (So in your example if namePrefixSuffixList contained "John Briggs Jr").

You could however loop through your List and do a contains check on the Strings themself, which will also return true for partial matches ("John Briggs Jr".contains("Jr") will return true for example):

```
boolean prefixSuffixFound = false
for ( String prefixSuffix : namePrefixSuffixList ) {
     if(entry.getKey().toLowerCase().contains(prefixSuffix) {
          prefixSuffixFound = true;
          break;
     }
}
```